# What's the difference between init() and __construct() methods in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

`init()` method :

```
public function init()
{
}
```

`__construct()` method:

```
public function __construct()
{
}
```

So, what's the differentce between them, and which should be used?

Comment: read this: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/3884-init-or-contruct/ it's from yii but still concept was same in both.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-object.html#__construct()-detail

Answer (score 11):

`init()` is the method of any object that extends from `yii\base\Object` (and the majority of objects extends from it).

From official docs:

> Besides the property feature, Object also introduces an important
>   object initialization life cycle. In particular, creating a new
>   instance of Object or its derived class will involve the following
>   life cycles sequentially:
>
> 1. the class constructor is invoked;
> 2. object properties are initialized according to the given configuration;
> 3. the init() method is invoked.
>
> In the above, both Step 2 and 3 occur at the end of the class
>   constructor. It is recommended that you perform object initialization
>   in the init() method because at that stage, the object configuration
>   is already applied.

It's recommended to use `init()`, you can even see it from source code and the extensions, but in some cases, you can use `__construct()`. There are some recommendations to implement that, you can find it on the same page in official docs [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-object.html).

`__constuct` is a native PHP language feature, you can read more info about that in PHP official docs in [this section](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).